# How can I access FormGroup from Directive - Stack Overflow

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

[image]

I could already access the formControl of my form with Ngcontrol,

but I would like to access the formGroup of this control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the form group like this: `(formControl as FormControl).parent;`

Comment: Thank you, I have just accessed in a similar way: this.formControl.control.parent